# How to add min height for particular grid

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid-layout, css

Im using  3 same grids with expanding text buttons and buttons are formatting different places because they have different amount text before the buttons. So my queston would be how to add specific min-height to a grid so the buttons would shown as on same level.

thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Great question, but we need to see what you're working with. Use a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U can use this

```
        
        tr.teste td {background: #00688B;height:100px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this css

```
yourclass {
min-height:100px;
}
```